# near ",": syntax error using foreign keys

Tags: sqlite

I keep getting the issue syntax error on the CREATE TABLE lines for all three tables that use the foreign key statements. I've been troubleshooting for a while and I'm stressing out as it's my first programming uni assignment.

```sql
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
CREATE TABLE Customer_info (
    customer_id VARCHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    address VARCHAR(255),
    login_name VARCHAR(255)
);
CREATE TABLE Payment_method (
    payment_id VARCHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY,
    billing_adress VARCHAR(255),
    card_holder_name VARCHAR(255),
    credit_card_nr INT,
    cvs INT,
    exp_date DATE
);
CREATE TABLE Product_list (
    p_name VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
    p_price INT,
    publisher VARCHAR(255),
    developer_studio VARCHAR(255)
);
CREATE TABLE Games (
    game_name VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
    game_desc VARCHAR(255),
    FOREIGN KEY (game_name),
        REFERENCES Product_list (p_name)
);
CREATE TABLE Software (
    soft_name VARCHAR(255) PRODUCT KEY,
    soft_desc VARCHAR(255),
    FOREIGN KEY (soft_name),
        REFERENCES Product_list (p_name)
);
CREATE TABLE Prof_info (
    profile_id VARCHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY,
    nickname VARCHAR(255),
    display_name VARCHAR(255),
    description VARCHAR(255),
    FOREIGN KEY (profile_id),
        REFERENCES Customer_info (customer_id)
);
CREATE TABLE Groups (
    group_id VARCHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY,
    g_name VARCHAR(255),
    g_desc VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Also I apologise if these are *easy* questions but I am sleep deprived, stressed & running out of time.

edit: removed the second question I had at the end as it was pointed out to me this isn't supposed to be done.

Comment: Remove the `,` before `REFERENCES`. It's `FOREIGN KEY (column) REFERENCES`. Does that solve the problem? And you can't ask a separate question using *Also* - SO is a question and answer site. Note that *question* is singular, not plural. If you have multiple questions, they need to be in separate posts. You may find that you have better experiences here if you spend a few minutes taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: Side note: names are a poor primary key. Consider what happens if you rename a product, all the references must change. Sharing the primary and foreign key is also likely to get you into trouble. Give every table a [simple, incrementing, integer primary key](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) named `id`.

Comment: @KenWhite Yes that does solve the problem and I apologise for having multiple questions, I edited the post to fix this.

Comment: Not a problem. :-) I was trying to help you understand how the site works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foreign key ... references` is a single expression.

```
FOREIGN KEY (profile_id) REFERENCES Customer_info(customer_id)
```

SQLite does not require a separate foreign key clause. You can do this inline.

```
-- A primary key that is also a foreign key is a bit odd.
game_name VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Customer_info(customer_id)
```

See `table-constraint` and `foreign-key-clause` in the [SQLite create table](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) grammar.

---

> Also would it be possible to state 2 foreign keys referencing different tables within the same table? How would I go about doing this?

Yes, just declare two foreign keys. Perhaps you're confused because you're making your foreign keys also your primary keys.

Here's a sketch of a better design. All of the pieces get their own table. All tables get an [auto-incremented integer primary key](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) which is assured to be unique and unchanging. Column names do not use prefixes, fully qualify them in queries if necessary. Table names are normalized as plurals.

```
create table publishers (
    id integer primary key,
    name varchar(255) not null
);

create table developers (
    id integer primary key,
    name varhcar(255) not null
);

create table products (
    id integer primary key,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    price numeric(6,2),
    publisher_id integer references publishers(id),
    developer_id integer references developers(id)
);

create table games (
    id integer primary key,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    description varchar(255),
    product_id integer references products(id)
);
```